# Override a member function with different return type

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, overriding, redefinition

Consider the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
   public:
      virtual int func()
      {
         cout << "vfunc in base class\n";
         return 0;
      }
};

class derived: public base
{
   public:
      double func()
      {
         cout << "vfunc in derived class\n";
         return 0;
      }
};

int main()
{
   base *bptr = new derived;
   bptr->func();

   return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives an error for the above code that there is conflicting type for the overriden function. Why is it not possible to override a function in the derived class with a different return type ?

I believe, in-order to override a function, the base class virtual method needs to be redefined in the derived class. To redefine a method, the signatures of the methods has to be the same. Since return type is not part of the signature, i believe even if there is difference in return type, the method will still be redefined? In that case for the code above, virtual function `func` is redefined in the derived class with a different return type. But the compiler throws an error. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: For clarification's sake, what compiler is giving you what error?

Comment: @SionSheevok, GCC does at least: http://codepad.org/z7rXpCeK

Comment: @SionSheevok :I am using gcc 3.4.6

Comment: *Nod* I wasn't suggesting it doesn't give an error, but merely curious what the compiler was specifically trying to communicate.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Overriding essentially means that either the Base class method or the Derived class method will be called at run-time depending on the actual object pointed by the pointer.
It implies that:
i.e: Every place where the Base class method can be called can be replaced by call to Derived class method without any change to calling code.

In order to achieve this the only possible way is to restrict the return types of the overriding virtual methods to return the same type as the Base class or a type derived from that(co-variant return types) and the Standard enforces this condition.

If the above condition was not in place it would leave a window to break the existing code by addition of new functionality.

Comment: Als: `type derived from that(co-variant return types)`. That was critical for my understanding. Nice explanation. :)

Answer (score 15):

In order to override a virtual function, the return value must be exactly the same*. C++ will *not* automatically convert between `double` and `int` here - after all, how would it know what return type you want when calling from a derived class pointer? Note that if you change part of the signature (parameters, const-ness, etc), then you can change the return value as well.

* - strictly speaking, it must be 'covariant'. What this means is that the type you return must be a subset of the parent function's return type. For example, if the parent class returns a `base *`, you could return a `derived *`. Since `derived`s are simultaneously also `base`s, the compiler lets you override in this manner. But you can't return totally unrelated types such as `int` and `double`; just because there's an implicit conversion doesn't mean the compiler will let you do this kind of override.

Comment: `Note that if you change part of the signature (parameters, const-ness, etc), then you can change the return value as well`. If i do that then the function is not overriden right?

Comment: Exactly the same or a subclass, I think you mean.

Comment: `co-variant` return types are allowed for virtual functions.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur, correct, the function won't be overriden if the signature changes

Comment: @Als: For emphasis, may we offer you our chic *italics*, and this just in, **bold** face?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I do know, I just typed that in a jiffy :) and went to add an answer of my own,by the time i saw your comment and realized the *faux paus* it was too late to edit it.

Answer (score 10):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type). To summarize, you can only override a virtual function using a different return type if the types are [covariant](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html).

Comment: The *types* aren't covariant, the *override* is.

Comment: No, only your interpretation of it is a bit idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override, you should try to use template.

See the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
   public:
      template<typename X> X func()
      {
         cout << "vfunc in base class\n";
         return static_cast<X>(0);
      }  
};    

class derived: public base
{
   public:
      template<typename X> X func()
      {
         cout << "vfunc in derived class\n";
         return static_cast<X>(2);
      }  
};    

int main()
{
   derived *bptr = new derived;
   cout << bptr->func<int>() << endl;
   cout << dynamic_cast<base*>(bptr)->func<int>() << endl;

   derived *bptr2 = new derived;
   cout << bptr->func<double>() << endl;
   cout << dynamic_cast<base*>(bptr)->func<int>() << endl;


   return 0;
}
```

Of course, you dont need to declare it on two different class that way, you could do:

```
class base
{
   public:
      int func()
      {
         cout << "vfunc in base class\n";
         return 0;
      }  

      double func(){
        cout << "vfunc for double class\n";
        return 2.;

      }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Overriding is not posssible ,as the signatures are same and the only difference is the return value. The basic purpose of overriding is polymorphism but it is not  possible in the above example

Comment: The signatures are same here. The functions differ only in return type and return type is not part of the signature.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur thanks for telling , that is what I intended to mean

Comment: When overriding a method it is possible to change the return type as long as this change does not conflict (the type is covariant) with the declared method. This does not break the polymorphism as the covariant type of the override is also valid type for the method declaration.