# Is it possible to override a function by changing the return type from optional to non-optional in C++?

Tags: c++, overriding, option-type, folly

In C++, I have a parent function whose return type is [`folly::Optional<int>`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Optional.h). My question is: Can we override the function and return `int` in the derived function?

I know this is doable in Java. For C++, I searched for some documents and saw that C++ allows covariant return type for overriding function. But I didn't find if optional/non-optional is a case of covariant return type.

Comment: What would the function look like? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't anything about this `folly::Optional`, but if it is similar to `std::optional` or `boost::optional` then `folly::Optional<T>` and `T` are not covariant.

Comment: Some useful links on this topic that may answer your question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967303/override-a-member-function-with-different-return-type/8967350), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439782/overload-with-different-return-type-in-java).

Comment: What is the use case for which you want to do this? Returning an `optional` that is always set already work and seems fine, and that won't involve downstream users having to change their code too. If your derived class should never return an empty `optional`, and you want to check that, that might best be expressed using some form of postcondition and/or testing I'd think.

Comment: This question already has all you need to answer it.  Answer:  In C++ covariance (at the language specification level, not conceptual level) only applies to pointers related by inheritance.  So no.