# Why using a different return type in virtual function declaration throws an error instead of resulting in a redefinition?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, vptr

Base class:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual int f() const
        {
            return 1;
        }
};
```

Derived class:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
        void f() const {}
};
```

Above code throws a "return type is not identical/covariant error".

I've read few discussions on it. This one is similar but they only say that it will break the code if the return types aren't identical/covariants.
[Override a member function with different return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967303/override-a-member-function-with-different-return-type)

Why the behavior I'm expecting doesn't happen?

Expected Behavior: The VPTR in Derived points to Base::f() (I've read incase an override isn't provided for a virtual function, Derived objects will just uses the inherited class version ). Also it hides the name f() so now a call like this:

```
Derived x;
x.f();
```

should've called Derived::f() and a call like this:

```
x.Base::f();
```

should've called the Base::f() function. This doesn't seem like breaking the code.
Incase its upcasted, even then it shouldn't break the code because VPTR for both classes points to the same Base::f()

The only reason I can think of is that such a declaration(same signature and covariant/identical return types) is reserved for overriding virtual methods and we just cannot use it to cause the behavior I'm expecting.

Comment: What is the problem that `Base::f` is supposed to solve? Is `Derived::f` supposed to solve the same problem? If not, even by a very tiny bit, then they should not be named the same. And as an aside, polymorphism won't work if the return types are different, since you're not overriding the `Base` function, you're *shadowing* it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know I can simply avoid using the same name but I'm curious as to why this would break the code. I've learnt about what you've described as shadowing. It's part of my question that why the shadowing behavior isn't happening here. It right away throws a compile error.

Comment: It simply would not work with polymorphism, what you expect `((Base*)(new Derived))->f()` returns

Comment: @appleapple I'd expect it to return Base::f()

Comment: It's not polymorphism and no need to be virtual then.

Comment: Why it would break the code? If I call the function polymorphically and expect an int, but your "override" doesn't return anything, how can it work? What is supposed to happen? It breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica. I see. So would you say that just the signature is enough to tell the compiler that I'm attempting to override? I mean that is it how it goes: Compiler figures out that I'm attempting to override (and not redefine) *because* I used the same signature. Now that the compiler has established that, it checks to see if the return types match. Is this how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler encounters the matching signature (arguments, constness), it automatically makes the `void f() const` declaration virtual. So the definition of `Derived` is interpreted as:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void f() const {} // virtual keyword is added
};
```

It clearly looks like an attempt to override `Base::f()`. All this happens because the function signatures match in the `Base` and `Derived` class. If the signatures didn't match, then only would this be a redefinition in which case it would've hidden the `Base::f()` in `Derived` class.

Comment: I've found this answer in Thinking in C++ part 1. Personally I don't think this question should be deleted (or downvoted) since every time this question is asked people start giving suggestions to avoid it instead of explaining what is actually causing the error. However of course, it is up to the mods to see if it actually is serving any purpose to the website. Thanks to everyone for helping in comments.