# Different return value of an overridden class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ virtual function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type)

I have a simple but confusing question here. Is it legal to have a different return value type for overridden methods than the abstact ones defined in the base class?? I did that and the compiler didn't complain... could someone please explain?

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    int value;

public:
    virtual int getValue() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public MyBaseClass
{
    double value;

public:
    virtual double getValue(); // here!!! return is double, not int
};

double MyClass::getValue()
{
   return this->value;
}
```

The compiler totally accepted something similar (MSVC und MinGW)... could anyone please exaplain to what extent this is legal?

Comment: Why does your base class has int value if your subclass uses a double?

Comment: GCC 4.6.1 complained: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual double MyClass::getValue()’

Comment: Actually in my program it's not int and double. It's double and MathVector with 3 components. The base class generates scalar signal, and the derived class generates a 3D signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type is allowed to differ but only in a bery restrictive way and you code is illegal. The only way the return type of an override is allowed to differ is that can be covariant if yhe return type of the base is a pointer or a reference. Put differently: if the base returns a pointer or a reference to a base class the overrude is allowed to return a pointer or a reference, respectively, to a class derived of the base.

Comment: How do you explain that my code compiles? the method is even pure! if it's not overriden and defined as a new method, then the compiler has to complain about the pure method being not used!!! I'm really confused!

Comment: the code you posted doesn't compile

Comment: In my code, I have double (in the base class) and MathVector<3,double> (in the derived class, 3 is 3 dimensions), and the constructor of MathVector<3,double> accepts double as an argument. Could it be that the program is automatically doing implicit conversions to make it work?

Comment: If your compiler accepts the code you posted it is not following the C++ standard. The return type of an overriding function has to match or be covariant (which it can't if the base returns `int`. See [this example](http://ideone.com/nzwEp) for a proper error message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding ? it looks like you have written a method and nothing else.