# Inheritance - why is this illegal?

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, typechecking

I'm going through a C++ quiz. And came across the following code - it's illegal, but I can't understand why. Can anyone explain why this line:

```
Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();
```

generates the compiler error, "cannot convert from Shape* to Box"?
I assumed that `s1->duplicate()` is calling `Box::duplicate()` because `s1` actually points to a `Box` - but from the compiler error it looks like it's calling `Shape::duplicate()`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Shape
{
  virtual Shape* duplicate()
  {
    return new Shape;
  }

  virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Box : public Shape
{
  virtual Box* duplicate()
  {
    return new Box;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  Shape* s1 = new Box;

  Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();

  delete s1;
  delete b1;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Shape::duplicates()` returns a `Shape*`, which isn't a `Box*`. The runtime type you actually return has nothing to do with it. How could the compiler know that the `Shape*` returned actually points to a `Box`?

Edit: Think about this:

```
struct Shape
{
  virtual Shape* duplicate()
  {
    return new Shape;
  }

  virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Box : public Shape
{
  virtual Box* duplicate()
  {
    return new Box;
  }

};

struct Sphere : public Shape
{
  virtual Sphere* duplicate()
  {
    return new Sphere;
  }

};

Shape* giveMeABoxOrASpehere()
{
    if ( rand() % 2 )
       return new Box;
    else
       return new Sphere;
}

//
Shape* shape = giveMeABoxOrASphere();
// What does shape->duplicate() return?

Box* shape = giveMeABoxOrASphere();
// shoud this compile?
```

Comment: Hmm. Well - I suppose I was thinking along the lines, that if the compiler can accept `Shape* s` = new Box` then it would somehow *know* that `s1` is now a pointer to a Box. It's late, I think my brain is fried. . .

Comment: @BeeBand: There's an important difference between `Shape* s = new Box;` and `Box* b = new Shape;`.

Comment: @BeeBand in this case you could find out with a `dynamic_cast`, so the type info is not completely lost. It's just unavailable to the compiler.

Comment: @BeeBand "_suppose I was thinking along the lines_ (...)" yes, the compiler **could** have an inference engine. Just like humans can make inferences. Please, describe mathematically the inference engine you expect the compiler to have (the implementation will certainly be trivial given a good mathematical description). ;)

Comment: @FailedDev "Box is a Shape" . . . I'm with you on this, but then I can't make the mental leap to and "therefore s1->Duplicate() must call Shape::duplicate()". I am trying tho :-)

Comment: @BeeBand I didn't say it calls `Shape::duplicate`. The call is resolved at run-time, the compiler doesn't know which method is called. But since it's a pointer to `Shape`, it looks at the definition and sees that `duplicate` returns at least a `Shape*`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - ohhhh ok I think I get it now, so at compile time, the compiler just cares about the return type of `Shape::duplicate()`, because `s1` is a pointer to a `Shape`?

Comment: @BeeBand yes. At run-time, the method indeed returns a Box. But this is a simple example. If you look at the code I added, you'll see it can get a lot more complicated.

Comment: "_How could the compiler know that the Shape* returned actually points to a Box?_" Let me add: How could the compiler **in general** know

Answer (score 16):

C++ language is statically typed. The decisions about the legality of your call are made at compile time. The compiler, obviously, cannot know that `s1->duplicate()` returns a pointer to a `Box` object. Under these circumstances, it would be illogical to expect it to accept your code.

Yes, `s1->duplicate()` indeed calls `Box::duplicate` in your example, but how do you expect the compiler to know this? One can say that it is "obvious" from your specific example, but the specification of this language feature makes no exception for such "obvious" cases.

Answer (score 1):

For the exact same reason

```
Shape* s1 = new Box;
Box* b1 = s1;
```

does not compile. The compiler does not care that `s1` refers to a `Box`, nor should it care.

If you know that `s1` refers to a `Box`, just say it:

```
Box *s1 = new Box;
```

A note about syntax: the parsing rules for `Box * s1;` are (very simplified):

```
declaration := type-name declarator ;
declarator := name 
            | * declarator
```

so the parsing is:

```
   Box        *       s1        ;
                   ^^^^^^^^
                  declarator
^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
type-name         declarator
```

and the grouping is `Box (* (s1) )`

It is considered best style to write `Box *s1;` because it is more consistent with the parsing than `Box* s1;` If you declare more than one variable in one declaration, the `Box*` syntax can be confusing:

```
Box* x, y;
```

`x` is a pointer to `Box`, but `y` is a `Box`, as the parsing is:

```
Box (*x), y;
```