# C++ virtual functions base return type suggestions

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, virtual, return-type

I need a base class that gives me primitive type of data's pointer. I add a function in it. I derived types of class. I used void * to support all primitive types as a return type but it is like old C days. It is not good for OOP. Does one have an suggestion to do in a proper way in OOP?

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
    virtual void *getPtr() = 0;
    virtual ~base() {};
};

class derivedAType : public base {
protected:
    int _i;
public:
    derivedAType(int i): _i(0) { _i = i; };
    virtual ~derivedAType() {}

    virtual void *getPtr() {
        return static_cast<void *>(&_i);
    }
};

class derivedBType : public base {
protected:
    short _s;
public:
    derivedBType(short s): _s(0) { _s = s; };
    virtual ~derivedBType() {}

    virtual void *getPtr() {
        return static_cast<void *>(&_s);
    }
};

int main()
{
    base *b1 = new derivedAType(1203912);
    base *b2 = new derivedBType(25273);

    std::cout   << "b1 : "   << *(static_cast<int *>(b1->getPtr()))
                << "\nb2 : " << *(static_cast<short *>(b2->getPtr()))
                << std::endl;

    delete b2;
    delete b1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you only have C++ build-in type?

Comment: just no... use templates

Comment: Are there any other differences in the classes? If no, you can use `tempalte`s.

Comment: I can't use templates because I want to store all of them in a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the base class a template class with the data type as the template variable

```
template<typename DataType>  
class base {
virtual DataType* getPtr() = 0;
//...
};
```

and

```
class derivedAType : public base<int>
```

But this changes base class to a template class which means you cant store them together, `base<int>` is different from `base<short>`

If this isnt acceptable, the other options is just a tad bit cleaner than your code but abt the same, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type). Basically derived class return types can reflect their true type and i think it should get automatically converted to `void*`, so you dont have to *manually* cast the pointer.

Comment: Yes, this is not what I want because I want to store them like std::vector<base *> _v;

Comment: but how will you use them if you have no idea what type they are returning?

Comment: You could give him more sample code regarding how to use it. :P

Comment: @KarthikT I don't want to decide which type where I store them. I want to decide it in realtime and different part of the flow. Objects creation place, store places and calling places are different. I don't want to know which type I have in the store places.

Comment: then i cant think of anything cleverer than a type enum that tells you what type it is, and a IsType() function to find if it is of that type. Each of your derived classes would respond correctly to that call to let you know type of data and you can cast accordingly.

Comment: @KarthikT Thank you! I needed to be sure that I am not missing something. Now I can continue to write my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your problem. But maybe a double callback can help:

```
class Callback {
public:
  virtual void do_int( int i ) const = 0;
  virtual void do_short( short s ) const = 0;
  /* ... */
}

class base {
public:
    virtual void do_stuff(const Callback & c); /* will need a more telling name */
    virtual ~base() {};
};

class derivedAType : public base {
protected:
    int _i;
public:
    derivedAType(int i): _i(0) { _i = i; };
    virtual ~derivedAType() {}

    virtual void do_stuff(const Callback & c) {
        c.do_int( _i );
    }
};

class derivedBType : public base {
protected:
    short _s;
public:
    derivedBType(short s): _s(0) { _s = s; };
    virtual ~derivedBType() {}

    virtual void do_stuff( const Callback & c) {
        c.do_short( _s );
    }
};

class print_callback : public Callback {
public:
  virtual void do_int( int i ) const { std::cout << i; }
  virtual void do_short( short s )  const { std::cout << s; }
}

int main() {
  base *b1 = new derivedAType(1203912);
  base *b2 = new derivedBType(25273);



  std::cout   << "b1 : ";
  b1->do_stuff(print_callback());
  std::cout << "\nb2 : ";
  b2->do_stuff(print_callback());
  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete b2;
  delete b1;

  return 0;
}
```

Of course you can simplify this by just storing the created print callback, and using it twice.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! In this approach I would need to do every algorithm in a class which derived from Callback. It is not suitable for my situation. I need to have the pointer of the type from outside of this mechanism.