# Should I avoid upcasting in implementation classes when wrapping an API

Tags: c++

I am writing some c++ code and want to use SFML for my GUI implementation. 
Rather than exposing the internal types, I am trying to write a pure virtual GUI class, as well as some related classes, for example a Surface for drawing to. I then have my implementations for each in SFML.
My problem comes where the GUI's draw(Surface s) function requires access to the SFML type sf::Texture which I need to access from my Surface object.

Now, I know that any Surface in my code will use the same API as the GUI class, as I only have the one implementation. I *am* trying to write good code, as this is primarily a learning exercise, and I believe this would break the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

I've tried to outline my issue in as simple code as I can below:

```
class Surface {
  // ...
};


class SFML_Surface : public Surface {

public:
  sf::Texture* get_texture() {
    return _surface->getTexture();
  }

  // ...

private:
  sf::RenderTexture* _surface;

};



class GUI {

public:
  virtual void render(Surface *s) = 0;
  // ...

};


class SFML_GUI : public GUI {

public:
  void render(Surface *s) {
    SFML_Surface *surface = static_cast<SFML_Surface*>(s);
    if(surface == 0)
      return;
    this->_window->render(surface->getTexture());
  }

};
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to go from here, I can't think of an obvious way to address the inter class dependency without a cast in some section.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on the above code, or discussion on alternative approaches. Or, as the title asks, is upcasting a bad idea in this specific situation?

Thanks in advance.

Code Edit: dynamic_cast should have been a static_cast

Comment: you could add `get_texture()` as a virtual function to `class Surface`, right?

Comment: the problem is, it has to return a pointer to an sf::Texture, which is specific to the implementation. If I return a void pointer, I'd still need to cast that.

Comment: First tell us why `s->render()` won't work.

Comment: sorry, do you mean having the surface do the render call?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the textbook OOP example.

Comment: By the way it's a *down* cast, not *up* cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Surface {
  // ...
  virtual TextureBase* get_texture() = 0; 
};


class SFML_Surface : public Surface {

public:
   sf::Texture* get_texture() {   // define sf::Texture to inherit from Texture Base
     return _surface->getTexture();
}

// ...

private:
   sf::RenderTexture* _surface;

};
```

The idea is return type doesn't need to be the same, as long as it is  [covariant with the original return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type).

Comment: This looks like what I had in mind, I didn't realise about covariant return types. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly covariant return types help here?