# Is there something equivalent to `instancetype` in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have a base class `Base` from which `A` is derived.

I would like to write something like this

```
Base *unsafeRelease() {
    --_refCount;
    return this;
}
```

… so that I can call `unsafeRelease` on instances of `Base` subclasses.

The problem, as I see it, is that using this code will involve upcasting and downcasting in all intended cases. I would like to specify, somehow, that I will return a pointer to an instance of a subclass of `Base`. Is this possible?

Comment: Please take a look at `std::enable_shared_from_this` and `virtual`.

Comment: I think that I do not, in this case, want a `shared_ptr`. This is all in a C++ library that has a C wrapper. `virtual` does look like the correct direction. Wouldn't I still need to override each subclass? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type

Comment: You want a virtual destructor for proper destruction, otherwise just override what you have to. Why do you think you should not use a `shared_ptr`? Regarding your literal question: `typeid` gives you the instance type of objects given as type with at least one virtual function. Also useable on the class type itself.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Maybe so, if `delete` is used somewhere with a base class type.  But not just because of the code shown here.

Comment: @Deduplicator: `shared_ptr` can't be used across library boundaries, which it sounds like he has.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is not an issue, because he's wrapping it all.

Comment: C++ is statically typed. Every function has one and only one type.

Answer (score 1):

Derive your `Base` from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and allocate your objects with `make_shared`.
Overhead with a good library is `2*sizeof(size_t)+sizeof(std::shared_ptr)`, without extra allocations.

That allows you to hand out raw pointers as opaque handles and still recover the shared_ptr, and it efficiently deals with the requirement to use the matching deallocation function.

Wherever you need to, you can then use `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr`.

An alternative is defining the ref-count, functions `Release`, `AddRef` and virtual destructor in `Base`, managing your ref-counts manually (Take a look at `IUnknown`, the base interface of all COM classes. Consider making your class derive from your platforms implementation of it).

About `instancetype`: The `typeid`-operator is what you want. You just need at least one virtual function for it to work (in which case the destructor should be virtual too, in nearly every case).

Comment: I have no idea whether this (`enable_shared_from_this) will work so I can't accept it yet. I'll have to try it which may take a bit.

Comment: No haste. If there are any more questions, I will look again.

Comment: I am currently(already) using the ref count method. It led me to this question.

Comment: I am not sure that this can be done without more casting. The typedefs visible in C would need to be `void *` or something ambiguous like that which will mess with the shared pointer's deallocation.

Comment: Why? Give them the standard opaque pointer idiom: `typedef struct Base Base;` Just like it's done for `FILE`.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to declare soemthing like  `typedef struct Base shared_ptr<Base>`?

Comment: No, you can just use raw pointers to `Base`, without giving any more info to the user than that `Base` is probably some kind of `struct`.