# why compiler complains cannot initialize "Derived" with an rvalue of type Base

Tags: c++, derived-class

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const { return new Base(*this); }
    // ...
};
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived* clone() const override { return new Derived(*this); }
    // ...
};
int main() {
    Derived *d = new Derived;
    Base *b = d;
    Derived *d2 = b->clone();
    delete d;
    delete d2;
}
```

i compile above code in the latest version of Xcode, and compiler complains

```
cannot initialize a variable of type "Derived*" with an rvalue of type "Base*"*
```

at `Derived *d2 = b->clone()`.

But I already make clone `virtual` and let the `clone()` in Derived return `Derived *`.

Why do I still have such problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of `Base::clone()` is `Base*`, not `Derived*`. Since you are invoking `clone()` through a `Base*`, the expected return value is a `Base*`.

If you invoke `clone()` through a `Derived*`, you will be able to use the return type of `Derived::clone()`.

```
Derived *d = new Derived;
Derived *d2 = d->clone();   // OK
```

Also,

```
Base *b = d;
Derived *d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b->clone());  // OK
```

Also,

```
Base *b = d;
Derived *d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)->clone();  // OK
```