# C++ Virtual Method return different derived types

Tags: c++, return-type, virtual-functions, static-typing, covariant-return-types

Referencing this question: [C++ virtual function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type)

Let's consider the following set of objects.

```
class ReturnTypeBase
{
};

class ReturnTypeDerived1 : public ReturnTypeBase
{
public:
    int x;
};

class ReturnTypeDerived2 : public ReturnTypeBase
{
public:
    float y;
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ReturnTypeBase* Get() = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
    virtual ReturnTypeDerived1* Get()
    {
        return new ReturnTypeDerived1();
    }
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
public:
    virtual ReturnTypeDerived2* Get()
    {
        return new ReturnTypeDerived2();
    }
};
```

Can these objects be used in the following way?

```
Base* objects[2];

objects[0] = new Derived1();

objects[1] = new Derived2();

ReturnTypeDerived1* one = objects[0]->Get();

ReturnTypeDerived2* two = objects[1]->Get();
```

I'm assuming since the return types are covariant(?), that the set of objects above is legal C++. Will the appropriate Get() method be called? Can the pointers one/two be assigned the return value of the Get() method without casting?

Comment: Did you mean `ReturnTypeDerived1* one = objects[0]->Get();`?

Comment: @flatmouse Yes, nearly got the edit in. :D

Comment: Do you have a use-case in mind?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm writing an Entity-Component system where the entity doesn't know what type (in the code sense) of components it has, and therefore you can't interact with the components via the entity's interface, which would've been nice. I guess I was trying to reproduce the syntactic sugar of C# extension methods, where each new type of component would also define accompanying extensions to the entity interface. The C++ way (which I've decided to go with) is to use free functions, actually functors in this case, to extend the interface. It's just a little less convenient.

Comment: Would it be possible to use templates so that the code wouldn't have to "know" but could still "know" the types?

Comment: My ideas involving templates still look a little clunky. I can live with the functor route. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code will not compile as written. Because `objects[0]` has static type `Base*`, invoking the `Get` function results in a pointer with static type `ReturnTypeBase*` being returned. Since this is an overridden virtual function, the derived class's `Get` function will be called as you would expect, and the returned pointer would actually point to a `ReturnTypeDerived1` object, but the compiler can't prove this. You would need a cast:

```
auto one = static_cast<ReturnTypeDerived1*>(objects[0]->Get());
auto two = static_cast<ReturnTypeDerived2*>(objects[1]->Get());
```

If you make `ReturnTypeBase` a polymorphic type, you can use `dynamic_cast` here instead to avoid undefined behaviour if you happen to be wrong about the dynamic type.

Comment: Isn't there an error here? Shouldn't the `dynamic_cast` be `static_cast`?

Comment: @flatmouse You can also use `static_cast` but then you have no way of telling whether you were wrong about the actual type.

Comment: The `dynamic_cast`s won't work because `ReturnTypeBase` is not a polymorphic type.

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdb8e11112f37a0a) with g++ or MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

As written, you will get compiler errors on the .Get() call.
If you want to avoid that, make the assignment to base class..

```
ReturnTypeBase * one = objects[0].Get();
ReturnTypeBase * two = objects[1].Get();
```

As long as you access 'one' and 'two' through abstract methods defined in the base class, (eg. a 'toString()' method), you won't have problems with the internal data.

If you intend on treating the data the same across all instances of the base class, you might want to considering using a template class instead.