# Is it possible to fully emulate a virtual operator++(int)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, crtp

We cannot make `operator++(int)` `virtual` directly because of the return type problem. The usual advice is to apply the curiously named `Curiously Recurring Template Pattern`, which I implemented to the best of my modest understanding as follows:

```
// abstract numeric type
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    virtual T& operator++() = 0;
    virtual T get() const = 0;
    virtual string toString() const = 0;
    virtual T operator++(int) {
        T old(this->get());
        ++*this; // calls operator++() from derived class
        return old;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a) {
        return os << a.toString();
    }
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};

// signed numeric type
class S : public A<S> {
public:
    S(long l) : m_l(l) {}
    virtual S get() const { return m_l; }
    virtual string toString() const { return to_string(m_l); }
    virtual S& operator++() { // no wrapping, caps at LONG_MAX
        if (m_l < LONG_MAX)
            ++m_l;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    long m_l;
};

// unsigned numeric type
class U : public A<U> {
public:
    U(unsigned long ul) : m_ul(ul) {}
    virtual U get() const { return m_ul; }
    virtual string toString() const { return to_string(m_ul); }
    virtual U& operator++() { // no wrapping, caps at ULONG_MAX
        if (m_ul < ULONG_MAX)
            ++m_ul;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    unsigned long m_ul;
};
```

Lots of code duplication, but at least it allows for constructs like the following to run, which is definitely a start:

```
template <typename T>
void pinc(A<T>& a) {
    cout << a++ << ' ' << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    S s(LONG_MAX);
    pinc(s);

    U u(LONG_MAX);
    pinc(u);

    return 0;
}
```

Sadly, it does not help with things like `vector<A*>`: `S` and `U` have no common ancestor. If I derive `A` from another base class, I also have to move the templated part there and the problem - ha! - goes recursive.

So, any suggestions?

Note to editors: Having learned my lesson, I saved the original this time. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. You want a base class `A` which will have both `++` operators, but their implementation can be overridden in derived classes. Is that the case?

Comment: @Angew I want a way around the (ostensibly artificial) limitation on the virtual function return type. Originally, virtual functions could not return different types at all; then it was relaxed to covariant types. Better than nothing but still not enough. Postfix increment is but an example of when this feature becomes especially illogical.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible within C++ type system, here is why:

Consider the following example: Let say we somehow achieve this and have `A* a` pointer to the base class from which `U` and `S` was derived. Then what will be the type of the `var = (*a)++;`? It could be either `U` or `S` depending on what `a` is pointing to. But compiler need to know return type *during compilation* because operator++(int) return `S` and `U` by-value.

I see the following ways to work around this problem but they all need to change the return types of `operator++(int)` in hierarchy to make them covariant (see [C++ virtual function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type)):

1. Return pointer to a (base) class within your hierarchy
2. If your types is integer types (like operator++ return `char`, `int`, `long` for different classes) then you can make them all return enclosing type: `long int`
3. Instead of returning direct values of your objects (`U` or `S`) return some kind of struct that is capable of holding *any* of these types. (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html for possible generic way to do this)

Comment: `boost::any` was my initial bet also. However, it would not allow me to do anything useful with the stored values, only cast them back to **statically** known types. (Or run them through a series of `if-else` statements comparing strings, which sort of defeats the whole idea.) If you have an example of using `boost::any` for my purpose, please share.

Comment: Well, look at the high level picture: if code does not know _anything_ about value being stored - it will not be able to use it anyway. So code need to know _something_ about types stored inside `any`. For example it might try to check if result belong to one or the other inheritance hierarchy and call virtual function appropriate to it and `any` class allow you to implement just that.