# C++ virtual function return type with shared pointers

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, virtual-functions

Is there any way to do what's proposed in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type) with shared pointer instead of regular C pointers?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: It says in the answer that only covariant types are allowed. Requirement for the covariant type is "both are pointers to classes or references to classes". `std::shared_ptr` doesn't count.

Comment: Are you wanting to return a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` that shares the same object as a `std::shared_ptr<Base>`?

Comment: No. `shared_ptr` of `Base` and `Derived` are not covariant.

Comment: I suspect that you just need to return `std::shared_ptr<Base>`. But do they really need to always be shared? If you can also use `std::unique_ptr<Base>` I would return those because they can always be converted to `std::shared_ptr<Base>` but not vice versa.