# Using auto with a virtual function … how to make this code run?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use auto in combination with a virtual function. Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
  virtual auto get() = 0;
  };

template <typename T>
struct bar : foo
{
    virtual T get() override {return new T;};
};

int main() {

  std::vector<foo*> Vec;
  Vec.push_back(new bar<decltype(1333)>);
  Vec.push_back(new bar<decltype(3.14159)>);
  Vec.push_back(new bar<decltype(true)>);

  std::cout << Vec[0]->get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << Vec[1]->get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << Vec[2]->get() << std::endl;
}
```

You can [see online at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/JzxEkz) that code does not compile. The compiler returns:

> error: virtual function cannot have deduced return type

Please help me to fix the above code.

Comment: This will not work in C++. `Vec[i]->get()` must imply a return type at compile time.

Comment: @Ayxan Ok, Thanks. Do you see a workaround?

Comment: Yes. You can return [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), or something else. Depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: The signature of all overrides of a virtual function need to be identical. You could return, `std::variant`, `std::any` or a polymorphic base class.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work in C++. `Vec[i]->get()` must imply a return type at compile time. How to do something like this depends on your needs. Assuming you have a closed set of types you want to work with, you can use `std::variant`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
  using ReturnType = std::variant<int, bool, double>;
  virtual ReturnType get() = 0;

  // you need a virtual destructor in all base classes
  virtual ~foo() = default;
};

template <typename T>
struct bar : public foo {
  using foo::ReturnType;
  ReturnType get() override {
    return T{};
  };
};

int main() {
  std::vector<foo*> Vec;
  Vec.push_back(new bar<decltype(1333)>);
  Vec.push_back(new bar<decltype(3.14159)>);
  Vec.push_back(new bar<decltype(true)>);

  auto const visiter = [](auto const elm) { std::cout << elm << '\n'; };

  for (auto& elm : Vec) {
    std::visit(visiter, elm->get());
    delete elm;  // don't leak memory
    elm = nullptr;
  }
}
```

Don't use raw-owning pointers in this context. They will lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The only problem is I don't know why your code ([online at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4yntpX)) gives 0 0 0 as output?

Comment: @BlueTune default initialized values for int, double and bool are `0`

Answer (score 0):

First, see here: [C++ virtual function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type)

Your problem is here:

```
virtual auto get() = 0;
```

A virtual function needs to have a known return type, or how will the overrides be checked to ensure covariance of their return types?

In particular, you seem to want `get()` overrides which return int, double, and bool.  But these types are not covariant with anything (they have no base class), so you can't do that, because there is no type you can put in place of `auto` that will actually work.

You could make a base class for the value types and then store wrappers derived from that:

```
struct BaseValue {};
struct IntValue : BaseValue {};
// etc
```

But then it's hard to see how you can do anything useful with the `BaseValue*` you'd `get()`.