# Returning a Derived pointer from a virtual function

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

```
class Base
{
public:
    // This version of getThis() returns a pointer to a Base class
    virtual Base* getThis() { std::cout << "called Base::getThis()\n"; return this; }
    void printType() { std::cout << "returned a Base\n"; }
};
 
class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    Derived* getThis() override { std::cout << "called Derived::getThis()\n";  return this; }
    void printType() { std::cout << "returned a Derived\n"; }
};



int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base *b = &d;
    d.getThis()->printType(); // calls Derived::getThis(), returns a Derived*, calls Derived::printType
    b->getThis()->printType(); // calls Derived::getThis(), returns a Base* !! Why ?
 
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:
called Derived::getThis()
returned a Derived
called Derived::getThis()
returned a Base

When calling b->getThis()->printType(); why b->getThis returns a pointer to Base ? not to Derived ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ virtual function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type). Especially, note this quote from the first answer: _The call to `clone()` will always return a pointer to a `Base` object, since even if it returns a `Derived*`, this pointer is implicitly convertible to a `Base*` and the operation is well-defined._

Comment: Note that `b->getThis()` must return a pointer-to-base. With dynamic polymorphism, a compiler generally cannot know the exact (dynamic) type of `b->getThis()` expression at compile time. So, it has no other option than resolve the type of this expression as a pointer-to-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When calling b->getThis()->printType(); why b->getThis returns a pointer to Base ?

Because `b` is a pointer to `Base`. And the type of the pointer returned by `Base::getThis` is pointer to `Base`.

> not to Derived ?

Because `Base::getThis` does not return a pointer to `Derived`.

Note that while the static type of the pointer is `Base`, the dynamic type is still `Derived`.

Comment: you mean the return type has to always match the return type in the base virtual function, right?

Comment: @slahOmar The type of the function call expression will be the static return type.

Comment: Hi @eerokia could you please give me a brief explanation about the static and dynamic return type? does the static return type mean that the returned type must be determined at compiler time? and since 'b' is a pointer to Base, the return type was determined to be Base pointer

Comment: @slahOmar I mean the static type of the pointer. The pointer is to `Base`, so the return type of any function `X` called through the pointer will have the return type of `Base::X`. C++ is a statically typed language, and dynamic things cannot affect the types of expressions.

Comment: Static type means what the compiler sees. The compiler doesn't know that `b` actually points to a `Derived`. It only knows it points to a `Base` so you get whatever `Base` has.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `virtual` does. You told the compiler that `b` points to a `Base`. It doesn't magically know that it *actually* points to a `Derived`, unless you use polymorphism. You do that by putting `virtual` on your function declarations. If you don't do that, you don't get polymorphic calls.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism allows a base class to present a base class interface but behaved in a derived class way. Polymorphically returning a derived class breaks this model since the holder of a base pointer will not have a reliable interface to work with.

If you have a pointer to a base class but really must work with a derived class you must either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` to the derived type where you use the class (in your case in the main function). Casting in C++ can be unsafe so you a better off relying on polymorphism where possible.