# Can you have a virtual function of type Parent class and then override it as Child type (c++)?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

Given the following structure of a Parent class and 2 childs.

```
class Data{
protected:
    int data;
};
class TreeData: public Data{
    // something
};
class PlantData: public Data{
    // something
};
```

Then, somewhere else I have another class structure to recover the data:

```
class RecoverData{
protected:
    string ip;
    int commTimeout;
public:
    virtual Data getData();
};
class RecoverTreeData: public RecoverData{
public:
    TreeData getData();  //Incorrect
};
class RecoverPlantData: public RecoverData{
public:
    PlantData getData(); //Incorrect
};
```

Logically this is not going to work because you define a return type, but then you return a different one. However, is there any way of obtaining a similar behavior? (Taking into account this class structure).

Comment: No, C++ does not support covariant return types by value, it would lead to slicing.

Comment: As your classes are polymorphic (i.e. have virtual functions), you can have your three `getData()` functions return *pointers* to the class objects: `virtual Data* getData();`, or even *references*: `virtual Data& getData();`. And then, e.g. `TreeData* getData();` or `TreeData& getData();` in the derived class(es).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665155/4165552 - good explanation

Comment: I see, thank you all!